# What can I do to improve the very poor performance of Rage?

Tags: rage

I have Sapphire HD 6790 graphics card and Intel i2100 CPU, with the latest drivers installed, and still can't really play Rage.

When I start a new game the intro video plays fine, but when game actually starts it's like I have PC from 10 years ago - the game runs with an FPS of below 5.

I've tried with almost every solution I can find on forums, etc, but nothing has helped yet. So what should I do to get Rage running acceptably on my PC?

Comment: ATI CATALYST 11.8 MY FRIEND AND YOU ARE OK.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://segmentnext.com/2011/10/04/rage-crashes-textures-fix-fov-fps-freezes-errors-and-graphics-fixes/) is a nice guide what to do with what issues, below is what I had to do to get it working for myself.

Note that the game is terribly optimized, you can say it is almost "random" how well the game will perform. If you can get past the game freezing every 5 seconds be happy, slow loading textures are annoying but you can at least play the game, and trying to fix them will bring back the freezes a few times before you can get them to work at least decently.

Here is what I did to get the game working acceptably on my machine:

- Install **Rage Update 1**, if you use Steam this will have been done automatically,  otherwise a quick web search will turn it up..
- Try [these](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/GPU121AMDCatRagePerfDriver.aspx) drivers, if you haven't updated yours for some time now (I had 11.10 at the time-beta).
- `(C:/)/Users/YourName/AppData/Local/id software/rage`
  Make sure you have this path on your computer, most likely you will be missing the last `rage` folder, so if you don't have it just create one.
- Open AMD Vision engine (the control center for your graphic driver, you should have icon in system tray) and under gaming→3D check "**`disable catalyst A.I.`**" and **turn off triple buffering** (this step helped me most).
- Last option is to edit the **Rage config**, more details are [here](http://www.gamepur.com/news/5615-rage-pc-version-tips-adjust-graphical-settings.html) and you can find many more configuration files on the internet. Some will improve your performance and some will decrease it, so if the game starts to work decently avoid this step as it is a tiresome one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked Nov 5th, but since then there have been a few releases of the ATI drivers, what I ultimately did was just wait with Rage until drivers matured.

I know other people will tell you to tweak this, and tweak that, but my ATI 6970 2GB had severe stutter and was unplayable.

After the ATI driver updates all ran smoothly and I was able to just max out the game.